# Use parameter as column name in table-valued function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[cycleplan_doctor_view] 
    (@Parameter1 INTEGER, @Group VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
        (SELECT * 
         FROM tbl_master_doctor 
         WHERE int_doctor_id IN (SELECT int_doctor_id 
                                 FROM tbl_master_MR 
                                 WHERE int_user_id = @Parameter1 
                                   AND @Group = 'Yes')
        )
```

When I am passing a value for `@Group`, I am getting empty table. But when I replace the value of `@Group` with its value it is working correctly.

I think I am missing some basic thing here.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @M.Ali :)

Comment: If `@Group` has a known, finite set of possible values, you can use `AND 'Yes' = CASE @Group WHEN col1 THEN col1 WHEN col2 THEN col2 ... END`. Otherwise you need dynamic SQL, which you're going to have a real hard time getting to work in a function.

Comment: value = CASE (column name) ?
in this format

Comment: I have NO IDEA what that means.

Comment: Short answer - you can't parameterize identifiers. long answer - there are workarounds if needed.

Comment: I am fool. :(. CASE worked :) Thanks @Aaron